# executar Task.WhenAll esperar e depois voltar executar

Tags: c#, asynctask

Estou tentando fazer um programa console, executar uma tarefa, aguardar e executar novamente e continuar nesse ciclo infinitamente.

Em teoria seria colocar a função dentro de um `While(true)` loop infinito, mas como a função é assincrona não está dando certo.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
        While(true)
        {
        ChamaTarefas();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }

    }
    private static async Task ChamaTarefas()
         {
           IEnumerable<UrlsProdutos> registros = db.UrlsTable.Where(w => w.Lido == false).Take(10);

            var tarefas = registros.Select((registro, index) =>
            {
                return Task.Run(async () => await ExecutaTarefasAsync(registro, index));
            });

         await Task.WhenAll(tarefas.ToArray());
    }



    public static async Task ExecutaTarefasAsync(UrlsProdutos registros, int index)
        {
         var produto = await ExtraiDados.ParseHtml(registros.Url, index);

         InsertAdo.MarcaComoLidoStpAsync(registros.UrlsImoveisVivarealId, index);
         await InsertAdo.InsertAdoStpAsync(produto, index);
         await ManipulacaoFoto.DownloadImgAsync(produto.FotosProduto, index);

       }
```

Mas é claro que não funcionou, ele executa a task, espera 10 segundos e já vai criando outra task, já tentei fazer algo do tipo:

```
var executando = ChamaTarefas();

    if(executando.IsCompleted)
```

Comment: particularmente achei muito confusa a explicação da pergunta. O que você quer dizer por "continuar nesse ciclo"? Não consegui entender exatamente onde se encontra sua dúvida. Em tempo: não é nada mau usar o Scheduler do windows. Ele possuir recursos muito mais avançados do que podemos implementar sozinhos e rápido. Existem alternativas em .NET com recursos avançados de agendamento de tarefas. Dê uma olhada em: http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Comment: no caso é como executar uma instrução, aguardar, executar novamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o seu objetivo é esperar `ChamaTarefas()` completar e depois esperar mais 10s, adicione `Wait()` na sua chamada no `Main()`:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(true)
    {
        // Chamar wait faz a thread bloquear até a tarefa ser completada.
        ChamaTarefas().Wait(); 
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
```